# Why null hypothesis of a statistical test is always opposite to what one wants to prove

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Why is it that the null hypothesis is typically the opposite of what one believes to be true?

Comment: It is a form of modus tollens: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens

Comment: Can you add some context to explicate what you have in mind here?

Answer (score 2):

The treatment of the null and alternative hypothesis is, by convention, asymmetrical. The null hypothesis is rejected at $p \ll 0.5$ (say $p = 0.05$ or $p = 0.01$). It follows that if the null hypothesis is rejected, then the null hypothesis is not just less likely, but compellingly so. If you want to convince someone of the alternative hypothesis, setting the opposite to the null hypothesis, then rejecting it at low p-values, is a convincing argument.

Imagine you found a new drug for some disease. If the new drug is effective, it will entail changing medical protocol, building a new factory for producing the drug, and so forth. Intuitively, in order to get this done, you don't need to show that the new drug is just more likely than not to work, but rather that it is *compellingly* more likely than not to work. Framing the converse as the null hypothesis is a step in that direction.